# GLSL point inside box test

Tags: opengl, glsl

Below is a GLSL fragment shader that outputs a texel
if the given texture coord is inside a box, otherwise a
color is output. This just feels silly and the there
must be a way to do this without branching?

```
uniform sampler2D texUnit;

varying vec4 color;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
  vec4 texel = texture2D(texUnit, texCoord);
  if (any(lessThan(texCoord, vec2(0.0, 0.0))) ||
      any(greaterThan(texCoord, vec2(1.0, 1.0))))
    gl_FragColor = color;
  else
    gl_FragColor = texel;
}
```

Below is a version without branching, but it still feels clumsy.
What is the best practice for "texture coord clamping"?

```
uniform sampler2D texUnit;

varying vec4 color;
varying vec4 labelColor;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
  vec4 texel = texture2D(texUnit, texCoord);
  bool outside = any(lessThan(texCoord, vec2(0.0, 0.0))) ||
                 any(greaterThan(texCoord, vec2(1.0, 1.0)));
  gl_FragColor = mix(texel*labelColor, color,
                     vec4(outside,outside,outside,outside));
}
```

[image: Here is the rendering result]

I am clamping texels to the region with the label is -- the texture s & t coordinates will be between 0 and 1 in this case. Otherwise, I use a brown color where the label ain't.

Note that I could also construct a branching version of the code that does *not* perform a texture lookup when it doesn't need to. Would this be faster than a non-branching version that always performed a texture lookup? Maybe time for some tests...

Comment: I'm always interested to see benchmarking results for stuff like this. I think in this case you might have to construct a scenario where many point-in-box tests become a bottleneck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `step` function to avoid branching and get the best performance:

```
// return 1 if v inside the box, return 0 otherwise
float insideBox(vec2 v, vec2 bottomLeft, vec2 topRight) {
    vec2 s = step(bottomLeft, v) - step(topRight, v);
    return s.x * s.y;   
}

float insideBox3D(vec3 v, vec3 bottomLeft, vec3 topRight) {
    vec3 s = step(bottomLeft, v) - step(topRight, v);
    return s.x * s.y * s.z; 
}

void main() {
    vec4 texel = texture2D(texUnit, texCoord);

    float t = insideBox(v_position, vec2(0, 0), vec2(1, 1));
    gl_FragColor = t * texel + (1 - t) * color;
}
```

Comment: Is there a 3D version?

Comment: @jjxtra: Yes. It's very easy to extend.

Answer (score 5):

Based on damphat's answer, I've implemented a function for a smooth transition between inside and outside the rectangle:

```
float inside_rectangle_smooth(vec2 p, vec2 bottom_left, vec2 top_right, float transition_area)
{
    vec2 s = smoothstep(bottom_left, bottom_left + vec2(transition_area), p) -
             smoothstep(top_right - vec2(transition_area), top_right, p);
    return(s.x * s.y);
}
```

Use the "transition_area" parameter to tune the size of the transition area between inside and outside the rectangle. The transition is faded **into** the rectangle, not out of it. Also make sure the "transition_area" parameter is smaller than the distance between "bottom_left" and "top_right" (in each dimension).
I'm successfully using this function to fade shadows in my engine (using shadow map coordinates).

Demonstration:
[image: inside_rectangle_smooth(v_texture_coordinate, vec2(0.0), vec2(1.0), 0.1)]
The above image is produced by calling:
`inside_rectangle_smooth(v_texture_coordinate, vec2(0.0), vec2(1.0), 0.1)`

Answer (score 3):

I just cam across this solution. Via https://github.com/stackgl/shader-school

```
bool inBox(highp vec2 lo, highp vec2 hi, highp vec2 p) {
    bvec4 b = bvec4(greaterThan(p, lo), lessThan(p, hi));
    return all(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following are two possible implementations:**

(Please, do comment on their performance, especially if you did happen to benchmark them.)

1. The comparison is done by a single call to `step()`:

   ```
    bool rectContainsPoint(vec2 rectBottomLeft, vec2 rectTopRight, vec2 point)
    {
        vec4 pt = vec4(point, -point);
        vec4 r = vec4(rectBottomLeft, -rectTopRight);
        vec4 inside = step(r, pt);
        return all(bvec4(inside));
    }
   ```
2. Could this simple-looking implementation be faster? Or is it slower?

   ```
    bool rectContainsPoint(vec2 rectBottomLeft, vec2 rectTopRight, vec2 point) 
    {
        vec2 bounded = clamp(point, rectBottomLeft, rectTopRight); 
        // return all(point == bounded); // comparison returns bool2
        return point == bounded;
    }
   ```

Comment: The second one doesn't seem to work in shadertoy.

Comment: The all() function in the second example should not be there. The == operator produces a simple bool, it can be returned directly (and since it's a single bool, not a vector of bools, compiling the all() fails with "no matching overload found").