# GLSL optimization: check if variable is within range

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

In my shader I have variable b and need to determine within which range it lies and from that assign the right value to variable a. I ended up with a lot of if statements:

```
    float a = const1;

    if (b >= 2.0 && b < 4.0) {
        a = const2;
    } else if (b >= 4.0 && b < 6.0) {
        a = const3;
    } else if (b >= 6.0 && b < 8.0) {
        a = const4;
    } else if (b >= 8.0) {
        a = const5;
    }
```

My question is could this lead to performance issues (branching) and how can I optimize it? I've looked at the step and smoothstep functions but haven't figured out a good way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out Jaa-cs answere wasn't viable for me as I'm targeting WebGL which doesn't allow variables as indexes (unless it's a loop index). His solution might work great for other OpenGL implementations though.

I came up with this solution using mix and step functions:

```
//Outside of main function:
uniform vec3 constArray[5]; // Values are sent in to shader

//Inside main function:
float a = constArray[0];
a = mix(a, constArray[1], step(2.0, b));
a = mix(a, constArray[2], step(4.0, b));
a = mix(a, constArray[3], step(6.0, b));
a = mix(a, constArray[4], step(8.0, b));
```

But after some testing it didn't give any visible performance boost. I finally ended up with this solution:

```
float a = constArray[0];

if (b >= 2.0)
    a = constArray[1];
if (b >= 4.0)
    a = constArray[2];
if (b >= 6.0)
    a = constArray[3];
if (b >= 8.0)
    a = constArray[4];
```

Which is both compact and easily readable. In my case both these alternatives and my original code performed equally, but at least here are some options to try out.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the problem depicted and avoid branching the usual techniques is to find a  series of math functions, one for each condition, that evaluate to 0 for all the conditions except the one the variable satisfies. We can use these functions as gains to build a sum that evaluates to the right value each time.
In this case the conditions are simple intervals, so using the step functions we could write:

x in [a,b] as `step(a,x)*step(x,b)` (notice the inversion of x and b to get x<=b)

Or

x in [a,b[ as `step(a,x)-step(x,b)` as explained in this other post: [GLSL point inside box test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751080/glsl-point-inside-box-test/37426532)

Using this technique we obtain:

```
float a = (step(x,2.0)-((step(2.0,x)*step(x,2.0)))*const1 + 
                (step(2.0,x)-step(4.0,x))*const2 + 
                (step(4.0,x)-step(6.0,x))*const3 + 
                (step(6.0,x)-step(8.0,x))*const4 + 
                step(8.0,x)*const5
```

This works for general disjoint intervals, but in the case of a step or staircase function as in this question, we can simplify it as:

```
float a = const1 + step(2.0,x)*(const2-const1) +
                   step(4.0,x)*(const3-const2) +
                   step(6.0,x)*(const4-const3) +
                   step(8.0,x)*(const5-const4)
```

We could also use a 'bool conversion to float' as means to express our conditions, so as an example `step(8.0,x)*(const5-const4)` is equivalent to `float(x>=8.0)*(const5-const4)`

Comment: a typo: step(a,x)-step(b-x)

Comment: What does this notation mean `[a, b[`?

Comment: @IC_ is a common math notation that means the a is included in the interval but b is not. For example [0,1[ means all the numbers greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'm used to `[a, b)` notation so that I thought it mean something else

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid branching by creating kind of a lookup table:

```
float table[5] = {const1, const2, const3, const4, const5};
float a = table[int(clamp(b, 0.0, 8.0) / 2)];
```

But the performance will depend on whether the lookup table will have to be created in every shader or if it's some kind of uniform... As always, measure first...

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll give it a try! No need to create the table in every shader it will keep it's values throughout the application. Is it better to use a uniform than creating a const outside main function like const float table[5] = {const1, const2, const3, const4, const5}; ?

Comment: @Johan: I'd expect uniform to be better. You can read this related answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/61262/39753

Comment: That link rather compared variables outside or inside the main function while my question was more about const vs uniform. In that regard there seems to be little or no difference as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478629/6242828

I'll mark your answer as accepted since it answers my original question though

Comment: Upon testing this didn't actually work, apparently you can't have variable indexes (I get error "Index expression must be constant"). This is while running in browser, OpenGL ES.